# correct value instead of array

Tags: activerecord, yii2

scenario is crm with tables account, account_contact, contact and account_contact_role. The latter contains roles like 'project lead' or 'account manager' for the combos defined in the junction table.

My challenge is the account view, that is listing also the connected persons with their roles. I want my grid to show: Doe | John  | employee.

The problem is now when the contact has 2+ entries in the junction table. How can I print the correct role for the row? As you can see in the code I solved it the static way which shows only  1 out of n times the correct value. Tried it with inner join without success. Is it a problem of the search in the model or with the access in the view?

the relation from the account model to the contacts:

```
    public function getContacts($role = null)
{
    // many-to-many
    return $this->hasMany(ContactRecord::className(), ['id' => 'contact_id'])
        ->via('accountContacts')
        ->innerJoinWith(['accountContacts.role'])
        ->andWhere(['account_contact.account_id' => $this->id])
        ->andWhere(['account_contact_role.type' => $role])
        ;
}
```

the view

```
    <?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $model->getContacts('internal'),
        'pagination' => false
    ]),
    'columns' => [
        'lastname',
        'firstname',
        [
            'label' => 'Role',
            'attribute' => 'accountContacts.0.role.name',
        ],
        [
            'class' => \yii\grid\ActionColumn::className(),
            'controller' => 'contacts',
            'header' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New', ['contact-records/create', 'account_id' => $model->id]),
            'template' => '{update}{delete}',
        ]
    ]
]); ?>
```

defined relations are:

account has many accountContacts has one contact
accountContacts has one accountContactRole

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing account's contacts, so you have to list from Contact model.

Inside **Contact model** (or Contact ActiveQuery file):

```
public static function queryContactsFromAccountAndRole($account, $role = null)
{
    // many-to-many
    return ContactRecord::find()->innerJoinWith(['accountContacts' => function($q) use($account, $role) {
        $q->innerJoinWith(['accountContactsRole'])
        ->andWhere(['account_contact.account_id' => $account->id])
        ->andWhere(['account_contact_role.type' => $role]);
    }]) 
    ->andWhere(['account_contact.account_id' => $account->id]);
}
```

Now you have one record for each contact and the gridview will show all contacts.

Comment: Works like charm, thanks. Even thought I wonder if the 2nd (->andWhere(['account_contact.account_id' => $account->id]);) is really needed?

Comment: No, it is not needed, because there is an inner join.